# Hudson build - MStest to not consider Inconclusive test as failure

Tags: hudson, mstest

We are having couple of test cases marked as inconclusive for maintenance, issue is with our Hudson build which is considering  Inconclusive test cases as Error.

We have enabled failonerror = "true"  in build xml. Guess MsTest is making decision on error status and not Hudson.

is there any command line argument to ignore Inconclusive test as error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

MSTest reports `Inconclusive` as separate from failure, but returns a execution result of `1` if any tests are inconclusive (unlike NUnit, which does not). The build will interpret the `1` result code as a failure.

There is no command line option to turn this off (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx )

It may be possible to turn off the `failonerror` flag, and add a build step to parse for errors, but if you wish to turn off a test for maintenance, it would be better to use an `[Ignore]` attribute, like this:

```
[TestMethod, Ignore]
public void my_test () { ... }
```

Unlike NUnit, you can't add a reason for the ignore, so best leave a comment.

Comment: Similar discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733592/assert-inconclusive-and-ignoreattribute/15012540#15012540